# MVC Dropdown Validation with Required Data attribute

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, asp.net-mvc-4

I have implemented a dropdown Listi in MVC and by dropdown parameter has Required attribute, 
Here is the design:

```
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.loanTypeId, "", new { @class = "errorText arrow_box" })
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.loanTypeId, Model.loanTypes, "--Select Loan Type--", new { @class = "selectpicker selectSource loanTypeClass", onchange = "onLoanTypeHelocChange(this)" })
```

Here is my view Model property:

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Please Select Loan Type")]
public string loanTypeId { get; set; }
public List<SelectListItem> loanTypes { get; set; }
```

If I change the value of the default option or "Select Loan Type" option by firebug or any other developer console to any random value, my validation fails.
Even ModelState.IsValid remains true as value is present in my property.

How do we perform validation in this case?

I can check for validation in Server side by checking if the value is valid.. but is there any other general approach which can be used for all dropdowns in my application?

Comment: Is your `loanTypeID` a string in your database, or an `int`?

Comment: It's a string for now. I'm thinking to change it to int once the database is designed. I'm doing this as a dummy application for now. There is no database as of now.

Comment: Please made him int type variable and add simple validataion.

Comment: It still wouldn't solve the issue. I can assign a int value from Firebug console and my validation would still fail.

Answer (score 0):

Are those files add to your scope ?

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js"></script>
```

Comment: I have added the files.. My unobtrusive validation works great.. It's just that if i change the HTML from developers console (like firebug in firefox) and assign a random value to the Select Option of dropdown, the validation will fail.

Comment: So you don't have a real problem, it's just when you are testing or debbuging ?